¿Cómo puedo configurar de la mejor manera notificaciones con React Native y Expo?
Estoy desarrollando una app y estoy atorado justo en las notificaciones.
En modo desarrollo las notificaciones llegan súper bien. Después construí la app y, para mi sorpresa, no funcionan las notificaciones.
Cabe recalcar que en el catlog de la app todo está excelente, sólo que no despliega la notificación. Asumo que el código está bien; es por eso que tomo la decisión de no subir código.
¿Alguien podria ayudarme a orientarme?
    import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { MyStack } from './stacks/stacks';
import { PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { ProviderLogin } from './context/context';
import * as eva from '@eva-design/eva';
import { ApplicationProvider } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

export async function sendPushNotification(expoPushToken, msg) {
  console.log(expoPushToken, msg, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@TOKEN');
  const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'default' : 'tono.mp3', // Usando el sonido por defecto en Android
    title: 'Abarrotes Juliancito',
    body: msg,
    data: { someData: 'goes here' },
    channelId: 'default', // Usando el canal default
  };

  try {
    // Enviar el token a Drupal
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://elalfaylaomega.com/credit-customer/jsonapi/node/notification_push',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
        Authorization: 'Authorization: Basic YXBpOmFwaQ==',
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      },
      data: {
        data: {
          type: 'node--notification-push',
          attributes: {
            title: 'tokens guardados',
            field_token: expoPushToken,
          },
        },
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.request(options);
    if (response) {
      // console.log(response);
    }

    // Enviar notificación a Expo
    const expoResponse = await axios.post('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', message, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    console.log('Notificación enviada a Expo:', expoResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al enviar notificación:', error);
  }
}

function handleRegistrationError(errorMessage) {
  alert(errorMessage);
  throw new Error(errorMessage);
}

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      sound: 'default', // Usando el sonido por defecto
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }

  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      handleRegistrationError('Permission not granted to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    const projectId =
      Constants?.expoConfig?.extra?.eas?.projectId ?? Constants?.easConfig?.projectId;
    if (!projectId) {
      handleRegistrationError('Project ID not found');
    }
    try {
      const { data: pushTokenString } = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
        projectId,
      });
      console.log('Expo Push Token:', pushTokenString);
      return pushTokenString;
    } catch (e) {
      handleRegistrationError(`Error getting Expo Push Token: ${e}`);
    }
  } else {
    handleRegistrationError('Must use physical device for push notifications');
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState('');
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState();
  const notificationListener = useRef();
  const responseListener = useRef();

  const setToken = async (tk) => {
    console.log(tk, "toen");
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('NOTIFY-TK', tk);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then((token) => {
      if (token) {
        setExpoPushToken(token);
        sendPushNotification(token, 'Bienvenid@ \u263A');
        setToken(token);
      }
    });

    notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
      setNotification(notification);
    });

    responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });

    return () => {
      if (notificationListener.current && responseListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);  

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
        <ProviderLogin>
          <PaperProvider>
            <MyStack />
          </PaperProvider>
        </ProviderLogin>
      </ApplicationProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

    introducir el código aquí

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

Este código recibe OK en las notificaciones locales y en el APK tambien recibe OK, pero no muestra las notificaciones. Éstas ya las tengo activadas en la app, pero simplemente no las muestra. Sin embargo, si yo envio desde push notification expo  las muestra rápidamente.
